# Does the Nexus 4 have 4G?

Tags: 3g, 4g, nexus-4

I know it doesn't have LTE, but what about the 4G networks of other carriers?
If I happen to buy one, will I be able to use it T-Mobile's *"4G"* HSPA+ network?

Comment: What T-mobile is advertising as 4G is not actually 4th generation technology. It's more like 3.5G

Comment: Technically speaking, neither is LTE.  As per [ITU-R](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/4G#Technical_definition), in order to be considered "4G", a network must deliver 100 Mbit/s.  Only under heavy marketing pressure did ITU-R reconsider, and now recognize that WiMAX and LTE could be considered "early 4G".

Comment: Calling LTE "4G" is something I've gotten over ... calling HSPA+ "4G" is just a sad, sad joke.  Marketing > innovation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, [it has HSPA+](http://www.phonearena.com/phones/LG-Nexus-4_id7531) which is what T-Mobile's "4G" actually stands for.

This article on [AndroidAuthority](http://www.androidauthority.com/nexus-4-features-no-4g-lte-support-google-sort-of-explains-why-126815/) should help you understanding  why it doesn't have LTE.

Answer (score -1):

It appears the Nexus 4 does have an LTE Chip, but its not enabled. Here's a post to get it working: http://techcrunch.com/2012/11/23/how-to-enable-4g-lte-on-the-google-nexus-4/
I've seen a fair amount of Youtube videos of people enabling it and testing it.

Comment: You should try and summarise what's on the link in case it goes down.

Comment: Ahhh apologies.